# Obtaining 2nd Derivatives for LogLikelihood Function

Tags: matrix-calculus

L(β;σ^2) = -T/2*(log(2π))-T/2*(log(σ^2))-(1/2σ^2)*(y-Xβ)'(y-Xβ)

Can someone clarify that ∂^2 L/∂β∂σ^2 = (1/σ^4)*(X'Xβ-X'y) ??

My tutor has it as -(My answer) but I can't work out why. I'll assume this is a mistake unless this can be proved otherwise? I have sent an e-mail to him but he normally takes a couple of days!

Thanks

Comment: I was going to typeset your formulas so it's easier to read, but you are missing parentheses in the first line. please look at it closely.

Comment: How about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate L wrt $\beta$ gives $X'(y-X\beta)/\sigma^2$. (There are two minus signs which give the +). This is easy if $\beta$ is just a number, but also works if it is a vector. Differentiate wrt to $\sigma^2$ gives minus the quoted result as $\partial (1/x) /\partial x = -1/x^2$

Comment: Which = the result I got right?

Comment: I failed to notice that you had flipped the terms around in the brackets of your answer, so what you wrote above is correct.

Comment: Brilliant. I've also found another lecturers notes from a different university which clarifies my answer. Thanks for your help.